# Symfony Firewall checking key in header

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

Is there a way to check if the header of the request has a key value, compare with another value stored in the env and then give or not the access?

**Note: I want to do it inside the firewall in security.yml.**

Something like the "guard-authentication" from the docs but I don't need all those methods (getCredentials, getUser, etc... )

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a [kernel controller filter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html), then you can parse the header of the request and search for the required parameter. For the env var you can set it as a parameter as below

```
//services.yaml
parameters:
    your_variable: '%env(YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE)%'
```

then call it from [service container](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)

```
$var = $container->getParameter('your_variable');
```

and finally you can use a [voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) in your controller action to allow/deny access